# Rock-Paper-Scissors optimization

Tags: probability, optimization

So i was wondering how to optimize the following problem: 
basically its Rock Paper Scissors with the Probabilities of

$$P(R) = 0.4;\quad  P(S) = 0.3;\quad  P(Pp) = 0.3,$$
 basically Player 1 is more likely to use Rock. 
What Probability should Player 2 use if he knows this?
I came to the Conclusion:

$$P(R2) = r;\quad  P(S2) = s;\quad  P(Pp2) = pp;$$

$$P(\text{winning}) = 0.4 \cdot  pp + 0.3 \cdot  r + 0.3\cdot  s $$

and 
$$
1 = pp + r + s
$$
$$ 
0 \le  pp \le 1; 0 \le r \le 1; 0 \le  s \le 1
$$

Now how do I proceed this problem? 
Just trough testing I get that it has to be:
$$
pp = 1;\quad r = 0;\quad s = 0;
$$

but how do solve this. I cant use the derivative since it would give me the wrong answer.

Comment: You want to maximize a linear function $0.4p+0.3r+0.3s$ over the set $p+r+s=1,p\ge0,r\ge0,s\ge0$, which is a triangle with three vertices $(p=1,r=0,s=0)$, $(p=0,r=1,s=0)$, $(p=0,r=0,s=1)$. The maximum of a linear function over a polyhedron is attained on one of the vertices, so you can just try all three and see which one is the best.

Comment: For more background, see [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), in particular the Theory section.